# cannot Autowire a class from external jar in spring boot

Tags: spring-boot

Have a class A in a spring boot application. Have added a module in the pom, and i am able to import that class 'B' from that module in this class
but i am not able to autowire the same,

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
class A
{
    A(B b)
}
```

There are no compile time errors, but the application fails to start

`Parameter 0 of method <> required a bean of type <> that could not be found`

Tried annotating the main class with @ComponentScan({"package of class B"})  , no compile errors, but the application fails to start with same error, but with different classes.

thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

If you specify `@ComponentScan` with a specific package, Spring will **only** scan that package and subpackages for Spring beans. So if your different classes are in a different package structure, you have to add those packages as well in the annotation.